# Python: "Multiple" multiple arguments in function

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm a Python newbie, but I know that I can allow a variable number of multiple arguments in a function using `*args`.

This script looks for a `word` in any number of string `*sources`:

```
def find(word, *sources):
    for i in list(sources):
        if word in i:
            return True

source1 = "This is a string"
source2 = "This is Wow!"

if find("string", source1, source2) is True:
    print "Succeed"
```

However, is it possible to specify *"multiple"* multiple arguments (`*args`) in one function? In this case, that would be looking for multiple `*words` in multiple `*sources`.

As in, figuratively:

```
if find("string", "Wow!", source1, source2) is True:
    print "Succeed"
else:
    print "Fail"
```

How can I make the script discern what is intended to be a `word`, and what's supposed to be a `source`?

Comment: If you have multiple multiple arguments how would you call the function? How would python know which one to put which value in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't, because you cannot distinguish where one type of element stops and the other starts.

Have your first argument accept either a single string or a sequence, instead:

```
def find(words, *sources):
    if isinstance(words, str):
        words = [words]  # make it a list
    # Treat words as a sequence in the rest of the function
```

Now you can call it either as:

```
find("string", source1, source2)
```

or

```
find(("string1", "string2"), source1, source2)
```

By passing in a sequence explicitly, you can distinguish it from the multiple sources as it is in essence just one argument.

Comment: @VigneshKalai: in which case the voter could be more helpful by flagging the question as a duplicate. I doubt that that was their motivation however.

Comment: Where more than one type of argument is to be expected, my experience tells me to completely avoid `*` and `**` magics. It gets messy when you use keyword arguments, and does not feel completely "consistent", like in your example: words have to be passed as iterable, sources as varargs. It may not look so pythonic to write ``def find(words, sources)`` but in the long term the consistency and cleanliness beats the cool syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution to needing "multiple multiple sources" is to have `*args` be the first multiple and the second multiple being tuples.

```
>>> def search(target, *sources):
        for i, source in enumerate(sources):
            if target in source:
                print('Found %r in %r' % (i, source))
                return
        print('Did not find %r' % target)
```

You will find other examples of this kind of API design used throughout the Python core language:

```
>>> help(str.endswith)
Help on method_descriptor:

endswith(...)
    S.endswith(suffix[, start[, end]]) -> bool

    Return True if S ends with the specified suffix, False otherwise.
    With optional start, test S beginning at that position.
    With optional end, stop comparing S at that position.
    suffix can also be a tuple of strings to try.

>>> 'index.html'.endswith(('.xml', '.html', '.php'), 2)
True        
    >>> search(10, (5, 7, 9), (6, 11, 15), (8, 10, 14), (13, 15, 17))
    Found 2 in (8, 10, 14)
```

Note that *suffix* can be a `tuple of strings to try`.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question which is that the OP effectively wants to be able to handle `*targets` _and_ `*sources`.